# What regular expression should I use to match this date pattern: DAY.month.YEAR?

Tags: javascript, regex, datetime, date

I have this date format:

```
DAY.month.YEAR (today: 28.06.2011)
```

I will need a Regular Expression (RegEx) pattern for matching this date format.

Can anyone post a solution for this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032313/php-regex-date-validation

Comment: You really don't need a regex for this. To code the necessary logic into a regex (days in each month, leap years etc) would just be a mess.

Comment: any particular flavour e.g. sed, perl, python, ruby, c#? Match complete string or just "28.06.2011"? Any limitations, i.e. is "01.01.1066" a valid date?

Comment: yes, some limitations for ie, starting point from current year and so on, I'll use the expression in JavaScript... and it must not match only "28.06.2011", rather any date in that particular format ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Derived from http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.(19|20)\d\d
```

This matches a date in dd.mm.yyyy format from between 01.01.1900 and 31.12.2099. It will, however, still match invalid dates, because validating leap years, for example, can not be done with regex (at least not very easily).

However, a regex is probably unnecessary. Javascript example:

```
var date = "28.06.2011".split("."); // split up the date by the dots

// parse the components into integers
var day = parseInt(date[0]);
var month = parseInt(date[1]);
var year = parseInt(date[2]);

// if you want the date in a date object, which will fix leap years (e.g. 31.02 becomes 03.03
var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
```

Note that when creating a date object, `month` starts at zero.

Which method you use depends on what you need this for. If you want to *find* dates in a text, use the regex. If you simply want to parse the date into a date object, use the second method. Some extra validation is possibly necessary to make sure the date is valid, as the javascript `Date` object does not care about February having 31 days, it simply wraps over to 3. of March.

Comment: @Jonas: the problems that February poses cannot be solved with regex.

Comment: @Matt That's the point I was trying to make. +1 to the answer for adding another solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to match the **format** of the date, than it will be enough to use:

```
\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d
```

However, as David Hall pointed out in his comment to your question, you will still need to **validate** the date in your code. Doing this in a regex isn't easy, as you can see from Harpyon answer which - still making a "preliminary check that filter out many wrong possiblities" - also accepts 31.02.2011 as a valid date and misses out on the French revolution (14 July 1789).