# Checking if a string has 07.05.2013 date format

Tags: php, validation

Trying to validate a string to check if it has the format 07.05.2013, not sure how to approach it.

Thinking of checking if '.' are the 3rd and 6th characters, then checking if the rest of the characters are digits but I don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: Do you want to validate the characters or do you want to validate the date ?

Comment: Change '-' to '.' in regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032313/php-regex-date-validation

Comment: Is the format mm.dd.yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy ?

Comment: the format is mm.dd.yyyy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply need to parse the date, you can use the date time features of php.

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', '07.05.2013');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `DateTime::CreateFromFormat()` method. This will validate your input and create a date object at the same time (which you can then use to work with the date).

```
$dateObj = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('d.m.Y', $inputString);
```

If the date is invalid or is in the wrong format, `$dateObj` will be `false`.

If it is a valid date in the required format, `$dateObj` will be a `DateTime` object.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match('/^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d\{4}$/', $yourstring)) {
 ...
}
```

This will be true if your string matches expression like dd.dd.dddd where d is a digit.

Comment: you forgot the `^` and `$` to match from beginning to end

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) function:

```
$date= '07.05.2013';
$date_arr= explode('.', $date);
if (checkdate($date_arr[0], $date_arr[1], $date_arr[2])) {
    // validate your date here
}
```

Comment: I would add another check, `if(count($date_arr) == 3)`. This will prevent some nasty undefined offset errors ...

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $yourStringWhichMightBeADate);
if ($date)
{
    // it's a date, so use it
}
```

Or:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m.d.Y', $yourStringWhichMightBeADate);
if ($date)
{
    // it's a date, so use it
}
```

if the month is first rather than the day of month.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1:**

Here's the way I did it, it works with every input you decide to enter (e.g: "12.02.1996", "12.30.1996", "dasdsadas", and so on..)

```
public function valid_date($inputdate){
  $date = $inputdate;
  if (strtotime($date)){
     if (strpos($date,'.') !== false) {
       list($day, $month, $year) = explode('/', $date);
       return checkdate($month, $day, $year);
     }else{
        return false;
     }
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

If input date is 10/10/1996 which is also a valid format, or 10/02/1996, it won't accept them because I'm asking the user to use the format with ".". Just remove the "if" if you don't want to do this validation and that is it.

**SOLUTION 2:**

Found this at [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.checkdate.php), very clean and interesting!

```
    public function valid_date($date, $format = 'd.m.Y'){
        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
        return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```